# Three.js animation from blender

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

CURRENTLY, what's the best way to export skinned mesh animations from blender? I'm pretty sure I have the importing down, both for JSON and dae, but I can't get anything to work perfectly.

I've gotten JSON to the point where it seems like only a small portion of my animation will play, and that's after rolling back blender.

I thought it might have been the parent issue, so I tried no parent, parented, and as a modifier. I've tried all these variations with and without both the object and the armature selected and each seperately, I've tried to make sure there was only a single animation action, which from my understanding is fixed.

With dae, it seems to have some crazy scaling difference? And things seem to work sporadic. A model that will load into the editor (albeit w/no animations) in the examples won't load at all in the collada skinned mesh example/my created scene. And if I try to load a foreign model like the version of the avatar model from the three.js server, it shows up with no skin. And all of this required me to download the dev branch of three.js (at least to get my model to import at all)

My blend file:
http://97.95.26.94/examples/basic_animation.blend

I've spent three days working on this. It seems to be different for every version of blender/three.js

EDIT:

heres some code that I recently tried to get working. not sure where I was at on it, at this point I'm just trying every thing. Please ignore the loader above, thats for the rest of my scene. assume all the directories are right... because they are.

```
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
<title>Lost Towers - Level designer</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="monitor"
        style=
        "
            position:absolute;
            color:white;
        "
    >ladidda!!</div>


<script src='xxx/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='xxx/three.min.js'></script><script src="xxx/ColladaLoader.js"></script>


<script>

window.onclick= function() {
var temp= renderer.domElement ; 
    if(temp.requestPointerLock) temp.requestPointerLock();
    else if(temp.mozRequestPointerLock) temp.mozRequestPointerLock();
    else if(temp.webkitRequestPointerLock) temp.webkitRequestPointerLock();
}

/// initialize three.js
//init_scene();


var container;
container = document.createElement( 'div' );
document.body.appendChild( container );

//main renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: false });
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

      renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
      renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
      renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
      renderer.shadowCameraNear = 3;
      renderer.shadowCameraFar = 100;
      renderer.shadowCameraFov = 10;

      renderer.shadowMapBias = 0.03;

      renderer.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
      renderer.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
      renderer.autoClear=false;


    document.oncontextmenu=function(event){event.preventDefault();};

function onWindowResize() {

        windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    }   
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var delta=0;
var loader = new THREE.BufferGeometryLoader();
var camera;

var scene= new THREE.Scene();
// load a resource

var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.setTexturePath("xxx");

loader.load= function (a, b, c, d) {////////////////Ignore all this, its for loading scene from clara.io
    var e = loader,
    f = new THREE.XHRLoader(e.manager);
    f.setCrossOrigin(loader.crossOrigin);
    f.load(a, function (a) {
            var x=JSON.parse(a)
            if(x.images)
            for(var i=0;i<x.images.length;i++)
                {
                    x.images[i].url=loader.texturePath+x.images[i].url;
                }
      e.parse(x, b)
    }, c, d)
  }
loader.load('xxx/main.json',function ( obj ) {
          scene= obj;
          //console.dir(obj);
          loader.setTexturePath("xxx");

           scene.traverse(function(child){

                  if(child instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera)
                      {
                        camera=child;
                        scene.add(camera);

                      }

/////////////////////////////////////HERE//////////////////////////////////////////////                   



          });
                  var daeloader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
                daeloader.load( "xxx/main.dae", function ( collada ) {
                  console.dir(collada.scene); alert();
                     collada.scene.traverse( function ( obj ) {
                    if(obj.type=='Object3D')
                    obj.traverse( function ( child ) {
                        if ( child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh ) {
console.dir(child);
                            var animation = new THREE.Animation( child, child.geometry.animation );
                            animation.play();

                            camera.lookAt( child.position );

                        }

                        } );
                    } ); 


                     scene.add( collada.scene );

                } ); 







        },function(){loader.setTexturePath("xxx");});


main();




function main()
{

    requestAnimationFrame( main );
THREE.AnimationHandler.update( clock.getDelta() );

    if(scene && camera)
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}



</script>


</body>



</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you include code in your question. Links aren't permanent and it is considered bad practice.

Comment: the problem is that I have hundreds of things I've tried, and I dont really know what route was actually the most appropriate, give me a minute and I'll whip something up I guess, I dont think its a code issue though.

Comment: Try to pin point it out. Maybe a log file and the steps you used to get to the error?

Comment: I've added a basic test scene.

Comment: Plz, give version (Blender & Three.js)

Comment: The link to your `.blend` file no longer works - if you're still interested in this issue, could you post another? I think exporting to a glTF file and then loading with `THREE.GLTFLoader` is probably the most reliable option these days. FBXLoader is also worth trying.